# Definition of an array of pointer-to-members in combination with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

In an embedded application, I'd like to create a helper class which holds a list of pointer-to-member-functions of a certain class, where the helper class calls the member functions in succession. At the moment, I'm having troubles with the definition statement of the static array which holds the pointers. This is the code:

```
template<class C, class F>
struct FunctionSequence;

template<class C, class R, class... Args>
struct FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>
{
    typedef R(C::*PointerToMember)(Args...);

    template<PointerToMember... F>
    struct Type
    {
        static const PointerToMember f[sizeof...(F)];
    };
};

template<class C, class R, class... Args>
template<typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::PointerToMember... F>
const typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::PointerToMember
    FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::Type<typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::PointerToMember... F>::f[sizeof...(F)]
        = { F... };

struct Test
{
    void m1(int) {}
    void m2(int) {}

    FunctionSequence<Test, void(int)>::Type<&Test::m1, &Test::m2> fs;
};
```

Both Visual Studio 2013 and GCC 4.7.3 give errors on this line, where I'm trying to define the f variable, and initialize it with a list of the member function pointers:

```
FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::Type<typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::PointerToMember... F>::f[sizeof...(F)]
```

GCC gives the following errors:

```
expansion pattern 'typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args ...)>::PointerToMember' contains no argument packs
too many template-parameter-lists
```

Visual Studio gives the following errors:

```
error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand
error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'F'
error C3545: 'F': parameter pack expects a non-type template argument
```

Moreover, Visual Studio gives an additional error one line later:

```
error C3855: 'FunctionSequence<C,R(Args...)>::Type<F...>': template parameter 'F' is incompatible with the declaration
```

Is it even possible what I am trying to do? Is my code wrong, and is it fixable?

Comment: You could use a static member function (with a static local variable) instead of a static data member. However, I'm interested in what the correct syntax for the definition of the static data member is.

Comment: I've boiled the example down to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1da5782569e4dcbf), where the problem is the `typename outer<T>::type V` used as template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for shortening the problem! I tried to get rid of using the typedef in the template definition (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88cdbec69de33ebf)), but then I still get compile errors. GCC says "too many template-parameter-lists".

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95206e72ec23edf1 Wow that's the ugliest (not voluntarily obscured) thing I've ever seen: `R(C::*...F)(Args...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn @dyp comment into answer:

Don't use `typename outer<T>::type V` as template parameter.

You have to declare it that way:

```
template<class C, class R, class... Args>
template<R(C::*...F)(Args...)>
const typename FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::PointerToMember
    FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>::Type<F...>::f[sizeof...(F)]
        = { F... };
```

Comment: Of course the questions are: Is using `typename outer<T>::type V` illegal? Can you do something similar? (I mean, a non-type template parameter whose type is dependent on a nested type of a type dependent on the same template-declaration..)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to initialize it outside of class, if you can simply do this in C++11?

```
template<class C, class R, class... Args>
struct FunctionSequence<C, R(Args...)>
{
    typedef R(C::*PointerToMember)(Args...);

    template<PointerToMember... F>
    struct Type
    {
        static constexpr PointerToMember f[sizeof...(F)] = {F...};
    };
};
```

Comment: What is `F`? packed types?

Comment: can you expand the code context? As it is, I do not understand where is goes. Under `struct Type`?

Comment: Indeed, your solution works for GCC, thanks; unfortunately, Visual Studio 2013 does not yet support initialization inside the class. I am looking for a solution for both compilers, and I am therefore looking what is wrong with the definition of f when initialized outside of the class.

Comment: @Richard it's really to complicated. Have no idea how to do this.